# Given descriptions from different advertisers,generate a general description that isnt specific to any one advertiser?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

For e.g

"Buy the latest phones for 5000".

"Get nice offers for the latest phones . Visit our XYZ store now"

So the general description can be

"Get nice offers for the latest phones".

or

"Buy the latest smartphones at nice offers".

Both of these general descriptions do not mention about 5000 or the store name so they can be used.

I was thinking about breaking the descriptions, converting them into vectors and calculating the similarity with other descriptions. The one with the maximum similarity can be chosen as the general description.

Comment: Not sure if spam or valid question :/

Comment: It is a valid question. I have been assigned this task as my summer project.